# What is point of emitChange, addChangeListener, and removeChangeListener in flux

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

In the Flux examples, all the Store classes have functions for `emitChange`, `addChangeListener`, and `removeChangeListener`. They are the same in all the examples, eg:

https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/ThreadStore.js

and

https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js

If they are the same, why doesn't the library provide some common code? Why have this boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common code is in the implementation of `emit` and `on`, and `removeListener`.

This is just an example. In real life you might never remove a listener once your app starts. Or maybe you want to add some logging code to those methods. So these boilerplate examples may differ from app to app.

Even more importantly. Facebook's flux implementation is just an example. There are probably hundreds of flux implementations because they are fairly straightforward to build. The important characteristics are not in these minor details but in the design of how data moves through a flux architecture.

If you're interested, [here's a store](https://github.com/z5h/yocto-flux/blob/c0234a9934992be0fb9faf32e36dbd983853287a/example/src/index.js#L25) class using [my own minimal flux](https://github.com/z5h/yocto-flux) architecture. No boilerplate at all.